# How Do I copy a column into another column and create column if it is not present in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 columns A and B, Data I have is daily  from Feb to July.For Feb to march I dont have Column B. My Task is as follows

Task 1 : if  Column B is not present create a column in document and copy A Column to B

Task 2: If column already exists leave it with data.

**Tried so far:**
col.find({colb:{"$exisits:True", "$set"}})....

please guide me

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [MongoDB aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). The `$ifNull` operator is what you need.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "colb": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$colb",
          "$cola"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dpJHQYvNFE4)

With `$project`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "cola": "$cola",
      "colb": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$colb",
          "$cola"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MqOW6ceKbnk)